# mathematica dynamic shifter list

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, appendto

I want a shifter list for a input buffer. My code is:

//Simulate input whit Slider. Is work perfect. Only work for changes by the user.

`list = Table[0, {10}];
Slider[Dynamic[b, (b = #; list = Take[Join[list, {b}], -10]) &], {0, 
  10, 1}]
Dynamic@list`

//x is a simulation of data input

```
Dynamic[x = RandomInteger[10], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

//Shifter list. As 'a' change, the code is replayed.

```
Dynamic[Take[AppendTo[a, x], -10],UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

I want to run the code only for 'x' changes. No for changes of 'a'. Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your `Slider` is related to the question but here's an answer:

use `TrackedSymbols` to specify what can trigger second `Dynamic`.

```
Dynamic[x = RandomInteger[10], UpdateInterval -> .2]
a = {};
Dynamic[a = PadLeft[Flatten@{a, x}, 10], TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
```

no need for `UpdateInterval` then.

Keep in mind that operations in `Dynamic` will be performed only when such cell is visible. Maybe better approach is to use `ScheduledTasks` or regular `Do` + `Pause`.